# Way to parse a string into segments when segments are maximum size or terminated with a particular character

Tags: c#, parsing

I am looking to parse out a string in C# to get relevant data segments from the string.

The rule for one part of the data stream is for Address with this rule set:

Address with $ between address lines. Terminated with “^” if less than 29 characters.

Some examples:

*28 Atol Av$Suite 2$^*

*Hiawatha Park$Apt 2037^*

*340 Brentwood Dr.$Fall Estate*

There are other similar rules for segments but if I have a solid plan for this segment I can modified it for the rest of the parsing.

I am wondering if there is a regex that could be used.

I have.{0,29}\^ that seems to do the trick. I wasn't escaping the ^ initially.

thanks,
Dan

Comment: Please show some of what you have tried already to do. And for the given examples how will the output look like. Questions without showing effort are very quickly downvoted and/or closed...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.Split()` to do this.

```
string [] substrings = string.Split('$');
```

Now you have an array of strings that contains the values between the `'$'` characters.

Then, I imagine you just want to get rid of the `'^'` character on the last element of the array (if it exists).

```
int index = substrings.Length - 1;

substrings[index] = substrings[index].TrimEnd('^');
```

You can use regular expressions and Regex.Split(), but you really don't need it if all you need to do is split on `'$'` and trim `'^'`. Writing a regular expression for this would be overkill.

**EDIT:** Now that I think of it, you could split on both `'$'` and `'^'` and just discard the empty entries, saving you the trimming step.

```
string [] substrings = string.Split("$^".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

I'll leave the pre-edit code as-is since it's more explicit, and explains the usage better.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Unfortunately there may only be one address piece so no $ characters may be present. Given each segment is slightly different than the example I gave I think unfortunately I may need to build a custom parser that is very specific and counts characters and looks for special characters.

Comment: @user461051 The above code still works if you have no '$' delimiters. It will just return the original string since it wasn't split.

Comment: I really need to do all this inside a regex vs. having to do additional coding because our goal is to have our application configurable for this parsing so we don't have to create new releases for customers. We will have various formats where some will use different delimiters and they will be in different spots. I have ([^\^]{0,29})\^? for matching the address piece but that only gives me the full address. In theory I was thinking is there a way to somehow do a group match on the results of a group match? e.g. subparse what I get from  ([^\^]{0,29})\^? and have it return as additional groups

Comment: Check out `Regex.Split()`. You could build a regex using a custom set of delimiters, and then just return those results.

Comment: Thanks Eric.  The issue is I am trying to avoid building out my framework to support a second pass on the initial regex results. Right now my whole framework can be configured simply by one regex and then identify data fields to map to based on each match object returned. i can extend my framework to allow for configuration of 2nd pass for some fields but was hoping to avoid that.